# Ask the user again to access geolocation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, permissions, geolocation

I use HTML5 Geolocation  to get user coordinates.
But if the user does not agree to request access to GeoLocation, this will always be a problem when visiting the site.

I want to get access again when the user has been denied access.

How do I ask this user every time?

you can copy my code in this link 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error

```js
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    
    function getLocation() {
    
    navigator.permissions.query({
         name: 'geolocation'

     }).then(function(result) {
         if (result.state == 'granted') {
           
          //user before accept  


           alert(result.state)
          
         } else if (result.state == 'prompt') {
            
             alert(result.state)
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
         } else if (result.state == 'denied') {
       
     
      // user is denied

      // I want call request to accept geolocation again


         }
        
     });
    
    
    }
    
    
    
    function showPosition(position) {
      x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
      "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    }
    
    function showError(error) {
      switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
          x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
          break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
          x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
          break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
          x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
          break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
          x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
          break;
      }
    }
```

```html
  <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>
            
            <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
            
            <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: What's the connection between this question and "google-apps-script" (tagged)?

Comment: This discussion by Google about [User Location](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location) might be helpful.